# Maintain my whole if you want to protect

Tags: riddle

My first riddle will be easy, but as I said, is the first! Find the word and I hope you enjoy

> If you clip my right you'll find her
>   But if Clip both sides you'll find the reverse
>   Maintain my whole if you want to protect
>   But if you clip my left you don't wanna be there

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not certain but I think it might be

> Shell

If you clip my right you'll find her

> **She**[ll]

But if Clip both sides you'll find the reverse

> [S]**he**[ll] (opposite of she)

Maintain my whole if you want to protect

> Shell = hard protective outer case

But if you clip my left you don't wanna be there

> [S]**hell**

Why I'm uncertain

> On the right, I'm clipping two letters as opposed to one but the clues seem to fit well if we allow this which is why I have gone for this answer.